# OpenCV Pipeline Editor

Tags: python, opencv, pipeline

I am learning OpenCV (using python interface).  I'm not really sure what I'm doing, so I keep adding and removing functions (blur, threshold, contours, edge detection) and modifying parameters.

What would be very helpful is a UI that allows me to create a pipeline and add / remove functions, and then modify the parameters on the fly to see the effect.  Does that exist?  I have used Blender in the past and they have a node editor as shown below: 
[image]

You can connect the output of one function to the next and you can either enter or click and drag to change parameters.   Unfortunately, the nodes are somewhat limited in Blender, but it would seem to me that having a similar capability using the python interface for OpenCV would be possible.  I just wanted to know if it already exists and where I can get it if it does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are at least the following three.

- [ImagePlay](http://cpvrlab.github.io/ImagePlay/)
- [Adaptive Vision Studio 4.3 Lite](https://www.adaptive-vision.com/en/download/download-for-opencv/)
- [ImprovCV](http://www.adrianboeing.com/improvCV/)

I personally like ImagePlay the most.

Comment: Thanks for the great info Tobias.  Adaptive Vision has OCR model creation capability but ImagePlay doesn't.  Do you know of any pipeline editor on Mac with OCR model creation?

Comment: @Anthony: Sorry, but no.